# How to use appsettings.Development.json variables in code

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json. I need to assign the SmtpServer name depending on the environment.

The config file in appsettings.json is:

```
{ 
  "EmailConfiguration": {
   "SmtpServer": "mail.MYDOMAIN.com"
  }
}
```

And in appsettings.Development.json is:

```
{ 
  "EmailConfiguration": {
    "SmtpServer": "mail.MYLOCAL.com"
  }
}
```

When I assign the configuration in Startup ConfigureServices() like such:

```
var emailconfig = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>();
services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(emailconfig);
```

It always uses appsettings.json ('mail.MYDOMAIN.com') and NOT appsettings.Development.json.

How do I modify this code to use the correct environment settings?

Comment: What build configuration are you running under?

Comment: In VS I'm using the Debug configuration and within that I have: Environment variables Name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Value: Development.

Comment: you sould read the doc regarding configuration I think : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: Looks like P-Finny did everything under that doc page. @P-Finny Have you tried killing iisexpress?

Comment: You could also check if `env.IsEnvironment("environmentname")` returns true in your `Configure` startup method.

Comment: @DanSchnau I did one better and restarted my machine to make sure IISExpress was cleared out.  I've put in a variable in the Startup method and confirmed my environment is 'Development'.  After reading the documentation again on setup I am not seeing anything that specifically says returning a Configuration.GetSection() will get the environment specific variable.  Do you know if that should happen?  Or do I need to call a more environment specific method?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is that all I needed was the environment variables in the 2 different appsettings files. My problem was a missing closing bracket in one of my configuration settings which meant that the appsettings.Development.json would not replace appsettings.json variables since they didn't match.  Oops.....